# How to test Buffer Cache in Pintos (Pintos Project 4)

Tags: cache, buffer

I'm working on Pintos Project 4, specifically the Buffer Cache part.

I have completed the code, but I am unsure how to test whether it is functioning correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.